# Manipulating Elements that will later be created

Tags: jquery

I'm loading dynamically some html in a div element. Is it possible, to get an event when the elements of this html are available in the dom and then manipulating it? I want to add an attribute for each anchor elements with this query:

```
$("a[href^='/static/']").attr('target', '_blank');
```

Comment: You could handle a delegated click event and change the attribute then. (I can’t check whether that works right now, but it should.)

Comment: Show your script in detail.

Answer (score 1):

Try on function,

```
$(document).on('click', '#elementId', function(){

});
```

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
if($('#name_of_element').length>0){ //check if element exsist on dom
    $('#name_of_element').click(function(){
     //do something
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found an solution. I'm sure that this isn't the best solution but it works for me. Before I'll put the html in a property of my $scope in the angular controller, I call this function.

```
var addTargetToStaticLinks = function (html) {
  var dom = $('<div>' + html + '</div>');
  dom.find('a[href^="/static/"]').attr('target', '_blank');
  return dom.html();
};
```

And now my anchor elements have the attribute target with the value _blank.